# Cant schedule R script with cron

Tags: r, linux, web-scraping, cron, cron-task

This is my crontab[image]

It´s supposed that my script on R saves csv on my directory.

`write.csv(raw_data, paste0("/Users/marianafernandez/Desktop/prueba/data-raw/database_pulls/raw_data/raw_data_", Sys.Date(), ".csv"), na = "", row.names = F)`

If I run on my terminal: R Script scraping.R everything goes fine. But when I try to do my cronjob is not working, nothing happens. Help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**cron** is still supported by OSX but it has been [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html) in **launchd**.

You need to create a "[plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001762-104142)" file and place it in folder ~/Library/LaunchAgents. Example plist file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>example</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>Rscript /path/to/example.R</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>0</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>23</integer>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

You need to load this **plist** file into the **launchd** scheduler and start it:

```
 launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/example.plist
 launchctl start example
```

Name **example** corresponds to the field **Label** in the **plist** file.

Answer (score 1):

More likely than not you need to put the path TOO the `Rscript` in front of it `path/to/Rscript` and it will correct the problem...that worked for me.

Comment: Yes I tried with:  * * * * * /usr/local/bin/Rscript  /Users/marianafernandez/Desktop/prueba/scrapping.R but is not working

Comment: do you have permission to schedule crontab jobs? Depending on the system you may not have the required permissions

Comment: Yes, I set up the permissions on security and privacy -> full disk access and then I added crontab. I´m using macOS catalina v. 10.15.4

Comment: oh, I assumed it was linux. Interesting, I have never used it on my mac...but I have a scheduler that I use to ingest and email data reports to myself and my boss 4 times per day which runs from Mac OS using automator: https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/welcome/mac this link shares how to schedule tasks